# Further "で as 動作を行うときの様態 vs で as だ" clarifications

Tags: particle-で

asked this a while back: [で as 動作を行うときの様態 vs で as だ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/62877/%e3%81%a7-as-%e5%8b%95%e4%bd%9c%e3%82%92%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%86%e3%81%a8%e3%81%8d%e3%81%ae%e6%a7%98%e6%85%8b-vs-%e3%81%a7-as-%e3%81%a0). But i don't feel this aspect has ever become intuitive at all, especially for adjectives.

eg.

> 爽やかで抜けるような青空と、この香りとは対照的に、大きくせり出した柵のグレーが強い拒絶を示している。

(speaker in a prison by the ocean) The gray of the large jutting fence shows a strong rejection in contrast to the "爽やかで抜けるような(invigorating, like it was escaping)" sky and ocean scent.

> 結果は今ひとつでナンパにも技術が必要だと身にしみた

In the end I have come to realize "今ひとつで(i am lacking?)", even nanpa requires considerable skill.

i lean towards で as だ for both of these, but it's an very disjunctive read and very hard to naturally translate.

When does someone purposely choose to use this sort of sentence structure?

Comment: Where is 今ひとつで in your examples?

Comment: Woops I must have cut instead of copied

Comment: Your interpretation of both as であって is 100% on the nose. But I don't really understand what you're asking about; does "this sentence structure" mean the であって version? I'm not sure of any other way we would connect adjectives, nouns, and 形容動詞 like this. "The result was rather lacking, and really hit home the fact that even nampa requires considerable skill."

Comment: are you saying that 結果は is only limited to 今ひとつで and has no continuation to ~と身にしみた. The first sentence is definitely more disjointed than this one though.

Comment: It does continue to 身にしみた. "The result was rather lacking, and (the result) really hit home the fact that even nampa requires considerable skill."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both of your examples, で is not a particle but the te-form of the copula だ.

> 爽やか**で**抜けるような青空

Here, で is used to [join na-adjectives](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11198/5010) (e.g., 簡単で便利な "easy and handy"). 爽やかな and 抜けるような both modify 青空. Note that the adverbial form of a na-adjective ends with に (e.g., 爽やかに "refreshingly").

> 結果は今ひとつ**で**ナンパにも技術が必要だと身にしみた。

This is a rather simple compound sentence made by joining the following two sentences using the te-form of だ:

> 結果は[今一つ](https://jisho.org/word/%E4%BB%8A%E4%B8%80%E3%81%A4)だった。ナンパにも技術が必要だと身にしみた。
>   The result was less than satisfactory. I realized even *nampa* requires some skill.

This 今一つ is a lexicalized no-adjective. If this で were 様態のデ, 今一つで would have to modify the following predicate, which is 必要だ, but "I realized I unsatisfactorily need skill" would make no sense.